# How is the probability of a sequence occuring with BLAST calculated?

Tags: bioinformatics, homework, sequence-alignment

What is the probability that a given nucleotide/amino acid sequence will occur in the whole database program BLAST searches in? How this probability is calculated?

Answer (score 5):

According to [BLAST documentation](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/tutorial/#head5) statistics of local sequence alignment, when doing database searches, is done

> by treating the database as a single long sequence of length N.

N is therefore a sum of all sequences with varying sizes from a given database.

Underlying assumption is that

> query is *a priori* more likely to be related to a long than to a short sequence, because long sequences are often composed of multiple distinct domains.

To calculate the probability, we need to choose a scoring scheme (for ungapped example: choose a mismatch penalties), which for a query sequence gives us a statistically significance score $S$. Expected number of alignments with score of at least $S$ follows Gumbel extreme value distribution:

$$
E = Kmn\cdot e^{-\lambda S}
$$

where *m* is query length, $n=N$ and $K$ and $\lambda$ are distribution params.

Again, according to [docs](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/BLAST/tutorial/#head4) and its references, probability of finding at least one such seq would be $P=1-e^{-E_{(N)}}$, where $E_{(N)}$ is E-number for concatenated N-sequence and query sequence.